# Using state setter as prop with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand if passing the setter from useState is an issue or not.

In this example, my child component receives both the state and the setter to change it.

```
export const Search = () => {
  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState('');

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <KeywordFilter
        keywords={keywords}
        setKeywords={setKeywords}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

then on the child I have something like:

```
export const KeywordFilter: ({ keywords, setKeywords }) => {

  const handleSearch = (newKeywords) => {
    setKeywords(newKeywords)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{keywords}</span>
      <input value={keywords} onChange={handleSearch} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My question is, should I have a callback function on the parent to setKeywords or is it ok to pass setKeywords and call it from the child?

Comment: Your current code will set keyword with the event and not the value that was typed in the input. Maybe you wanted to do `(e)=>setKeywords(e.target.value)`?

Comment: @HMR good point. It is indeed an oversimplified code just to make sure that my question about hooks is understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to create an addition function just to forward values to setKeywords, unless you want to do something with those values before hand. For example, maybe you're paranoid that the child components might send you bad data, you could do:

```
const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState('');

const gatedSetKeywords = useCallback((value) => {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    console.error('Alex, you wrote another bug!');
    return;
  }
  setKeywords(value);
}, []);

// ...

<KeywordFilter
  keywords={keywords}
  setKeywords={gatedSetKeywords}
/>
```

But most of the time you won't need to do anything like that, so passing setKeywords itself is fine.

Comment: IMO you should not pass setter functions around especially to generic reusable components like Dropdown, RadioButtons etc. Your TypeScript in the child compeonent also gets unnecessary more complicated when you pass setters around instead of the child component just knowing that a callback gets called (`() => void`). A Child component should not have to know anything about the state that you manage in the parent. That makes reading your code unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

A setter of state is just a function value from prop's view. And the call time can be anytime as long as the relative component is live.